# How to fix the window size in Scene Builder?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have set the max/min width/height here

[image]

But it didn't seem to work,I still can change the size of my window when I preview it

Comment: can you share your code, which you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values you're setting are (probably) for the root `Node`. This won't prevent the `Scene` or `Stage` from growing or shrinking beyond the specified values. In fact, depending on the root `Node`, setting these values won't even stop said `Node` from growing or shrinking.

From Javadoc of `Scene`:

> The application must specify the root Node for the scene graph by setting the root property. If a Group is used as the root, the contents of the scene graph will be clipped by the scene's width and height and changes to the scene's size (if user resizes the stage) will not alter the layout of the scene graph. If a resizable node (layout Region or Control) is set as the root, then the root's size will track the scene's size, causing the contents to be relayed out as necessary.

If you want to constrain the size of a `Stage` you need to do it in code by setting the appropriate properties of the `Stage`: `minWidth`, `minHeight`, `maxWidth`, and `maxHeight`. Since you are setting `minWidth = maxWidth` and `minHeight = maxHeight` it would be better to use `Stage.setResizable(false)` (as mentioned in [Bernhard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52124749/6395627)). This option also prevents the `Stage` from being maximized which setting the min/max size properties does not do. Though on my machine the properties *do* stop the `Stage` from growing when maximized but it causes the `Stage` to jump to the top-left corner.

Since you don't have access to the preview `Stage` used by Scene Builder (as far as I know) I don't think you can constrain the size of the preview. One thing you may be able to deal with, however, is the fact the preview `Stage` opens to its previous size when closed. I'm not sure why this is default/unchangeable behavior but I'm *guessing* it's caused by using the same `Stage` each time. To resize the `Stage` to the preferred size you can go to:

```
Preview -> Preview Size -> Preferred Size (Width x Height)
```

[image: Screenshot of menu item in Scene Builder]

This requires the preview to be showing otherwise the menu item is disabled.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `.setResizable(false);` on your stage, should help.